# Preserving row format and formula when inserting new row in Google Sheets using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets database:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VzHY8fTq8OsXhpHYHESSSPxeVNOnqxpjcsyWJpbuEOs/edit?usp=sharing

'Base Stats' sheet (Sheet 1) is regularly updated with new rows added.  Row 1 is a header row.  Row 2 onward columns 5-8 have font colours applied.  Column 6 has a drop down list.  Columns 7, 12 & 13 have formulas. When a new row is inserted, currently it will not copy the formatting and formula detailed above.

I did some searching and I found this possible answer:

```js
function onOpen(e){
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
 ui.createMenu("Format sheet").addItem("Format", "setFormat").addToUi()

}
function onEdit(e){           //This is activated each time a modification happens in the sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet =ss.getActiveSheet()
  if(sheet.getSheetName() == "Base Stats"){
  var entryRange = e.range
  var range  = sheet.getRange(2,entryRange.getColumn(),1,entryRange.getNumColumns())              //This will be you range to get the formatting from row "1" and corresponding column based on the column being edited
  Logger.log(entryRange.getA1Notation())
  range.copyFormatToRange(sheet, entryRange.getColumn(), entryRange.getNumColumns()+entryRange.getColumn()-1, entryRange.getRow(), entryRange.getNumRows()+entryRange.getRow()-1)
  Logger.log(entryRange.getColumn())
  if(entryRange.getColumn() == 12){                                 //This column value will not be allowed modified except for row 1 of that column
    if (entryRange.getRow() != 2){                                  //The columns in row "1" will be allowed to modified
    e.range.setValue((e.oldvalue == undefined? "": e.oldvalue))
    }
  }
  }
}

function setFormat(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var firstRow = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn())
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange()
  firstRow.copyFormatToRange(sheet, 1, dataRange.getNumColumns(), 2, dataRange.getNumRows())

}
```

However, I'm not sure what I need to edit in the script to apply to my Google Sheets example?  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to copy formulas, change for `arrayformula`, example in M1

```
={"Score 
(Weighted)";arrayformula((H2:H*2)+(E2:E*1.5)+(F2:F+G2:G))}
```

immediately apply formatting for all columns (and whole columns) and you won't need to copy formatting rules

Comment: This works great thank you. The only problem I have is it populates the formula beyond the last row of data. For example, say row 100 is the last row with data, all rows from 101 and beyond, column M shows 0 as the formula continues.

Comment: you can ad a condition as `={"Score 
(Weighted)";arrayformula(if(H2:H="",,(H2:H*2)+(E2:E*1.5)+(F2:F+G2:G)))}`